# Erro de inserção no banco Oracle com Java

Tags: java, oracle

Quando faço um conjunto de inserções no banco, ele diz que apenas as informações do **curso** foram inseridas, mas as de **turma** não.

**Console**

```
STATUS DE CURSO: true 
STATUS DE CURSO: false
```

**JOptionPane**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TurmaDAO**

```
public class TurmaDAO extends DAO {

 public TurmaDAO() {
        connection = Conexao.getConnection();
    }

    public boolean inserir(Turma turma, Curso curso) {
        boolean status = false;
        sql = "INSERT INTO turmas VALUES (seq_id_turma.nexval, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            p = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            p.setString(1, turma.getNome());
            p.setString(2, curso.getNome());
            p.setString(3, curso.getPeriodo());
            p.execute();
            status = true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível armazenar os dados da turma\n" + ex);
        }
        return status;
    }
```

**Turma**

```
public class Turma {
    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public Turma(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

}
```

**TestaTurmaDAO**

```
public class TestaTurmaDAO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inserir();
    }

    public static void inserir() {
        Curso cs = new Curso("Sistemas de Informação", "Tarde");
        CursoDAO csDao = new CursoDAO();
        boolean csStatus = csDao.inserir(cs);
        System.out.println("STATUS DE CURSO: " + csStatus);

        Turma tr = new Turma("2SIA");
        TurmaDAO trDao = new TurmaDAO();
        boolean trStatus = trDao.inserir(tr, cs);
        System.out.println("STATUS DE TURMA: " + trStatus);
    }
```

**Estrutura do banco**

```
Nome          Nulo?    Tipo          
------------- -------- ------------- 
ID_TURMA      NOT NULL NUMBER(5)     
NOME          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100) 
NOME_CURSO    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100) 
PERIODO_CURSO NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
```

Comment: Ao inves de retornar uma caixa de dialogo, retorne a pilha de erros completa, para que se possa ver melhor o erro e a sua origem. E adicione essa pilha na pergunta.

Comment: Perdoe-me a ignorância, mas o que seria adicionar a pilha de erros? São aqueles erros que aparecem quando a aplicação quebra?

Comment: Comente a linha do optionpane e adicione `ex.printStackTrace();`. Quando estourar o erro, adicione na pergunta a pilha.

Comment: Adicionei a informação sobre a pilha de erros.

Comment: Onde é a linha 19 da classe CursoDAO?

Comment: Opa! Achei o erro! A sintaxe do insert tá com `seq_id_turma.nexval`, faltou o 'T' para ser `seq_id_turma.nexTval`, mas agora está dando outro erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem de erro descrita no `JOptionPane` diz que está acontecendo um erro de sintaxe.

Ao olhar para a sintaxe da variável `sql` no método `inserir()`, notei que está faltando um "T" na função `.nextval` de `seq_id_turma` do Oracle SQL.

Corrija a sintaxe adicionando um "T" e ela voltará a funcionar.